# Ruby: parsing message from confluence xml macro

Tags: ruby, xml, macros, nokogiri, confluence

I am trying to parse the message that says "this is a test"

```
<ac:structured-macro ac:name="warning"><ac:rich-text-body><strong>High</strong> This is a test!</ac:rich-text-body></ac:structured-macro>
```

I am using nokogiri in ruby and was able to parse this much and nothing else. To get this far, my code looks something like this:

```
xml = Nokogiri::XML(response)
body = xml.at("body").text
alert_body = alert[3]
```

I have wasted too many hours looking in the confluence rest api documentation and google for just general xml parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems are:

1. There is no `body` tag in your example XML.
2. You're dealing with XML-Namespaces so your selector needs to change.

Your XML sample is incomplete since it's missing the line that would define the namespaces, so this is a bit of a hack but should give you an idea what needs to be done:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<foo xmlns:ac="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<ac:structured-macro ac:name="warning"><ac:rich-text-body><strong>High</strong> This is a test!</ac:rich-text-body></ac:structured-macro>
</foo>
EOT

doc.at('ac|rich-text-body').text # => "High This is a test!"
```

Namespaces are useful but they can be a major pain in the neck. Nokogiri makes it pretty easy to deal with them, especially when using CSS selectors. Read Nokogiri's "[Searching an HTML / XML Document](http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html)" page's "Namespaces" section for more information.

Comment: Thank you! I was originally attempting to use something along the `doc.css('div#something strong')` and the using ruby to clean up the rest and it just was not pretty. Still a complete newb so I appreciate the help.

Comment: XML can be a real "experience". It was a great idea, and like so many others, once it hit the real world people found ways to subvert it, mangle it, and, in general, make the lives of programmers miserable. You'll get used to it.